# Use conditional logic in an array map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, jsx

Ok so I am using express-react-views as a templating engine and I am currently trying to make a working breadcrumb. On each route I pass a prop called "crumb" that is an array of the current location on the app. That array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        text: "Home",
        href:"/",
        active: false
    }, 
    {
        text: "Step2",
        href:`/page`,
        active: true
    }
]
```

Obviously this can be multiple steps down. The last step is the page you are on, so active is set to true. This is where my problem is. To render this on the page I am mapping this array to JSX like this:

```
const Breadcrumb = props => {
    return (
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            {props.crumb.map(crumb =>
               <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={crumb.href}>{crumb.text}</a></li>
            )}
        </ol>
    )
}
```

This code works fine but what the active page should have the class "active" on it and should not have an  "a" tag. So what I need to do it as it's mapping this array to check for the active:true value and then map a different element. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can try this out if you want both active and inactive links to be shown:

```
const Breadcrumb = props => {
    return (
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            {props.crumb.map(crumb =>
               crumb.active ? <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={crumb.href}>{crumb.text}</a></li> : <li class="breadcrumb-item">{crumb.text}</li>
            )}
        </ol>
    )
}
```

if you only want to show active links then you can use:

```
 const Breadcrumb = props => {
        return (
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                {props.crumb.filter(item => item.active).map(crumb =>
                   <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={crumb.href}>{crumb.text}</a></li>
                )}
            </ol>
        )
    }
```

Inside map you can check `crumb.active`, so it will either return true or false and based on that you can return respective element.

Comment: You maybe don't need the not, active doesn't need the a link.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want

```
const Breadcrumb = props => {
    return (
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            {props.crumb.map(crumb => {
                if(crumb.active)
                    return <li class="breadcrumb-item active"></li>
                else
                    return <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={crumb.href}>{crumb.text}</a></li>               
            })}
        </ol>
    )
}
```

Comment: This also works. I tried the exact same thing but it was giving all types of errors so I figured that it wasn't possible to do it this way. I must have had it wrong somewhere along the line. Thank you.